# A symbol name was expected! reserved code cannot be used without backquotes

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table staffs(
                    id integer not null auto_increment, 
                    fname varchar(20) not null,
                    lanme varchar(20)not null,
                    address varchar(50) not null,
                    bdate date not null,
                    sex varchar(6),
                    salary decimal(6),
                    job_type varchar(10),
                    constraint staff_pk primary key(id),
                    constraint staff_ck_jb_type 
                         check ( job_type ='admin' or job_type='tech' or job_type='sales'),
                    constraint age_chk 
                         check (DateDiff(YY,bdate,GetDate()) as age > 21)
                   );
```

2 errors were found during analysis.

> A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a
> column name without backquotes. (near "check" at position 297)
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "DateDiff" at position 304)

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DateDiff'

Comment: Does removing `as age` solve your problem? There's no need to declare an alias name (`age` in your example) in a `check` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your check syntax was wrong you can't define thee an ALIAS

Second mysql doesn't like no deterministic functions
Now(), curdate(),. getdate() don't work

so you have to circumvent it, like seen in the example

> ```
>     create table staffs(
>   id integer not null auto_increment, 
>   fname varchar(20) not null,
>   lanme varchar(20)not null,
>   address varchar(50) not null,
>   bdate date not null,
>         ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   sex varchar(6),
>   salary decimal(6),
>   job_type varchar(10),
>   constraint staff_pk primary key(id),
>   constraint staff_ck_jb_type check ( job_type ='admin' or job_type='tech' or job_type='sales'),
>   constraint age_chk check (timestampdiff(YEAR,bdate,ts)  > 21));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO staffs VALUES(NULL,'test1','test2','teststreet','2017-06-25',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'male',20000,'tech')
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'age_chk' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO staffs VALUES(NULL,'test1','test2','teststreet','1981-06-25',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'female',1000,'tech')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM staffs
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fname | lanme | address    | bdate      | ts                  | sex    | salary | job_type
> -: | :---- | :---- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------ | :----- | -----: | :-------
>  1 | test1 | test2 | teststreet | 1981-06-25 | 2020-07-20 13:15:32 | female |   1000 | tech
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16ad09eaa9de7d7767365ddf8452605c)*